# Unable to execute commands on Google Sheets API using Python - How to fix?

Tags: python, api, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to connect to google sheets through an API with python. I’ve gotten so close  as for them to recognize that I have a spreadsheet and return a name, but I can’t control it through various commands that I’ve tried. I’ve also changed the name for sheets and or worksheets. And brand new (1 mo) at python after a week of struggling with this, I decided to ask somebody for help.

I have created the service accounts, download it and renamed the .json files, Appear to be granted access, fail to get any spreadsheet commands to work. In the first code it recognizes the file’1’ with go.open(’1’). But can’t read the worksheet also named . Other commands are used afterwards with no success.

---

```
>>> import gspread
>>> from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
>>> scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
>>> credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('c:/API.json', scope)
>>> gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
>>> sheet = gc.open('1')
>>> sheet = gc.open('1').1
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> sheet.update_cell(1, 1, 'x')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#144>", line 1, in <module>
    sheet.update_cell(1, 1, 'x'
AttributeError: 'Spreadsheet' object has no attribute 'update_cell':
>>> sheet.update(A1')
         
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>> sheet.update('A1','1') 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#146>", line 1, in <module>
    sheet.update('A1','1')
AttributeError: 'Spreadsheet' object has no attribute 'update'
```

In  The next code  I made sure it wasn’t a problem with worksheet as a number

```
>>> import gspread
>>> sheet = gc.open('1').sheet33
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#148>", line 1, in <module>
    sheet = gc.open('1').sheet33
AttributeError: 'Spreadsheet' object has no attribute 'sheet33'
>>> sheet = gc.open('1').Sheet33
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#149>", line 1, in <module>
    sheet = gc.open('1').Sheet33
AttributeError: 'Spreadsheet' object has no attribute 'Sheet33'
>>> sheet = gc.open('1').1
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> sheet = gc.open('1').Copy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#151>", line 1, in <module>
    sheet = gc.open('1').Copy
AttributeError: 'Spreadsheet' object has no attribute 'Copy'

>>> sheet = gc.open('1').2 step
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Lastly just showing the different occasion when the python displayed the spreadsheet titles ‘Wordle…’ and ‘ 2 step’ .

```
>>> for spreadsheet in spreadsheets:
    print("Title:", spreadsheet.title, "URL:", spreadsheet.url)
    print(gspread_client.auth.signer_email)

    
Title: Wordle Ans Sheet URL: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MVuIrNEBtmwy5JfXVY2I85GVcVrT8V9lPLGHqhEd0Ls
wordle@friendly-maker-387519.iam.gserviceaccount.com
Title: 2-Step Calcs -wordle URL: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12MGWDnCuY3yaWN1oCNDUbKCXK5r2k6wC8qj7lktyBbk
wordle@friendly-maker-387519.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Comment: Why do you assume these members will be attributes of whatever `open` returns? Probably just use `sheet = gc.open(...)` and then access attributes of `sheet`; you can play around in the Python REPL to see what attributes it has with `dir(sheet)` and, of course, read the documentation for the module.